# Powershell ISE freezes during script execution if RDP connection is lost

Tags: powershell

I have a powershell script that depends on ISE (doesn't work right in normal console) due to the usage of forms.

When the script runs, it can sometimes take up to 10 minutes for the script to complete. This is not really an issue though... But if Powershell ISE is open and the RDP connection is lost (for example, another user connects to the session) PowerShell ISE becomes unresponsive and the script doesn't seem to run anymore. I've had the same on my local computer with different instances. For example if I lock my pc, it happens too.

Weirdly, I can still right-click the powershell ISE taskbar entry and get the popup. I can close from here fine even though the [x] doesn't work anymore. If I close this way, and the script had changes in it, Powershell ISE will ask me if I want to save my changes and does so, but any other form of interaction seems impossible.

Does anyone know what I can do to fix the issue? Is there any way I can update PowerShell ISE?

The server is Windows Server 2016, my pc is Windows 10 Pro x64 v2004

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As for this...

> I have a powershell script that depends on ISE (doesn't work right in
> normal console) due to the usage of forms.

***PowerShell.exe cannot display forms natively, by design. To be able to display the form, we need to add a line of code to the very top of our script to support the rendering of the WinForm/WPF Form.***

The ISE uses powershell_ise.exe, not powershell.exe or pwsh.exe (PowerShell Core).

***Your UX/UI code should never have a dependency on a code editor to run.***

```
Add-Type -AssemblyName  Microsoft.VisualBasic,
                        PresentationCore,
                        PresentationFramework,
                        System.Drawing,
                        System.Windows.Forms,
                        WindowsBase,
                        WindowsFormsIntegration

[System.Windows.Forms.Application]::EnableVisualStyles()
```

This is well documented in the PowerShell help files, all over the web. The ISE automatically loads UX/UI modules/namespaces, the console host does not.

> You do not need all in the list depending on what you are doing in
> your UX/UI/Form implementation.

Yet, it does not hurt/impact anything to load all the above and grants the flexibility that each brings. See the docs on each of them.

As for this...

> When the script runs, it can sometimes take up to 10 minutes for the
> script to complete

... this is not a UX/UI issue, it's our backend code, and it would take this long, whether you had a UX/UI or not.

As for this...

> But if Powershell ISE is open and the RDP connection is lost (for
> example, another user connects to the session) PowerShell ISE becomes
> unresponsive

... if your backend code stops/hangs, then your UX/UI has no idea what is going on and waits for your backend code to tell it to do something. UX/UI is not a code monitor and has no idea what your backend code is doing. UX/UI is just a display for results. If it does not get an action/event to respond to, it locks, by design. Also, by default, RDS/RDP logon to a server is no more than two connections at a time, which includes console. So, unless you buy and deploy a full RDS license per connection license you need, you are stuck with what you see.

The ISE (or another code editor), is an editor/designer for your scripts, not the execution of your script. Though you can test your code there, that is for debug purposes, not production.

You write code in the ISE/VSCode, etc., but your target run/execution environment is the console host. No user should have to open a code editor to run your code.

As for this...

> Does anyone know what I can do to fix the issue? Is there any way I
> can update PowerShell ISE?

...

1. Don't run this code in the ISE, unless you are designing/debugging/testing it?
2. Add the UX/UI namespace to the top of your script.
3. There is no updating of the ISE. As per MS, the current version of
   Windows PowerShell 5x and the associated ISE is depreciated.
   Meaning, no more work is going into either of them, other than
   bug/security fixes.

MS has stated that, though no more work is going into PowerShell v5x and the ISE; WinPS, and the ISE will be what they are today and they will be in OS/.Net full releases for the foreseeable future. So, those who prefer PSv5 and the ISE can continue using it.

> [PowerShell 6.0 Roadmap: CoreCLR, Backwards Compatibility, and
> More!](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/powershell/powershell-6-0-roadmap-coreclr-backwards-compatibility-and-more/#:%7E:text=Future%20of%20Windows%20PowerShell%20Windows%20PowerShell%205.1%2C%20much,receive%20major%20feature%20updates%20or%20lower-priority%20bug%20fixes)
>
> ***Future of Windows PowerShell
>
> Windows PowerShell 5.1, much like .NET Framework 4.x, will continue to be > a built-in, supported component of Windows 10 and Windows Server 2016.
>
> However, it will likely not > receive major feature updates or lower-> priority bug fixes***.
>
> With > PowerShell Core, we are actively addressing bugs that may have
> existed in previous versions of Windows PowerShell. We’re even open to
> contributions so that these bug fixes can be made by members of our
> community.
>
> There are no changes to the support cycles for the shipping version of
> Windows Management Framework (WMF).

[Thus, all effort in the cross-platform PowerShell Core (aka currently PowerShell v7 for Windows/OSX/Linux).](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/scripting/install/installing-powershell-core-on-windows)

There is no ISE for PowerShell Core. [The editor for PowerShell core is Visual Studio Code](https://code.visualstudio.com/Download) and to use PowerShell with VSCode, you need to install the PowerShell Extension.

well, you can actually use the ISE with Powershell Core, via PowerShell RunSpaces if you'd like. Here's how:

> https://old.ironmansoftware.com/using-powershell-core-6-and-7-in-the-windows-powershell-ise

Yet, with VSCode, you can have many shells open in the same editor at once, which has its advantages.

Youtube

> 'PowerShell for VSCode'
> https://www.youtube.com/results?search_query=powershel+for+vscode

***Still, none of the above obviates the need for the GUI namespace or other references in your scripts. You should always use them in any code editor you are using by default when you are using UX/UI stuff.***

Lastly, for long-running scripts, you should really look at using PowerShell background jobs.

> 'PowerShell Jobs long-running scripts'
>
> https://duckduckgo.com/?q=%27powershell+jobs+long+running+scripts%27&t=h_&ia=web

Comment: That's a nice write up, I use ISE for admin production purposes though for my script stuff I run adhoc but routinely so I think it's fine with that level of production I suppose just not stuff you want to automate while you step away so I get it. Background jobs and\or invoke-command  with scriptblock -asjob parameter maybe the same or not?

Comment: No worries. Full disclosure, for PowerShell, I use many tools (ISE/VSCode.Visual Studio/Sapien's PowerShell Studio, etc.) as needed, ***but most of my time, like you, is in the ISE. 95% of my day is spent there***. Very rarely am I ever in the console host natively. I support customers globally and I have to deal with whatever they allow. I still prefer the ISE even though I use other tools. So, I feel you. Yet, I write all code in the ISE but I shell out to the console host to run it, as needed. Thus, the jobs ting when needed, so my ISE session stays live/responsive.

Comment: Thank you so much for this answer. I will have to dive into this deeper when I get back to work on monday. For now a +1, the check may come monday if I get the script to work outside of PowerShell ISE, you earned yourself the check. :)

Comment: LPChip. No worries. Good to know it provided some edification on the use case. Keep us posted. Stay safe out there, and enjoy the holiday, well, that is if you are USA-based.

Comment: Awesome, implemented it, works like a charm! Thank you so much. :)

Comment: Awesome, and no worries. Glad it all worked out. Stay safe out there. and have a great memorial day if you are a USA type of course.  ;-}

Comment: I'm Dutch, europe. But thanks anyway. :) Stay safe. :)

Comment: ***;-}***  an1, and this is all the Dutch I know. `geen zorgen, blijf veilig`, just because I have had teammates from there in my past. I know, not really close to `no worries`, but well....